# The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length I

Tags: flutter, dart

This code throws an exception at this line

```
if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length > 1) {
```

The error is:

```
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Detail Of " + widget.barcode),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
        future: fetchAlbum(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length > 1) {
            return ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((e) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTileLocal(e['title'], e['value'].toString()),
                    Divider(color: Colors.black)
                  ],
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                "No Barcode Found",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Invalied Barcode"),
            );
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return Container(
              child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add the code for fetch album as well

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the length on null data. With `&&` operator you are not checking if data is null before trying to call `snapshot.data.length`.
Using `if` should prevent from calling on `null`.

```
if(snapshot.hasData) {
 if(snapshot.data.length > 1) {
    /// Do something with data...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot may or may not have some data, before calling some inbuilt function on it , such as length it's important to check if its not null

you did this

```
if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length > 1) 

//if the snapshot does not have data, it means snapshot.data=null; and as
//you are using && (and) operator it will check length on null and will
//throw error
```

correct way would be

```
if(snapshot.hasData) {

//hence here snapshot has some data and you can use .lenght on it 
 if(snapshot.data.length > 1) {
  }
}else{

}
```